# Why didn't Urame die when she was stripped?

Tags: akibas-trip

In episode 12 of *Akiba's Trip: The Animation*, Tamotsu strips Urame [down to her underclothes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PETgn.jpg). And if there's any of law of physics that's consistently obeyed in this anime, it's that if a Bugged One is stripped, it gets exorcised/killed.

As a Hazoku, she's not possessed, meaning there's nothing to exorcise in her case. So I would've expected her to die... but she doesn't. Indeed, she's about to get up and continue fighting with Matome and Tamotsu when [Arisa airdrops on top of her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq1BW.jpg) and knocks her out.

I haven't played the games - is there some sort of game-mechanic reason why Urame would've survived being stripped?

Comment: i get the feeling that one of the main reasons for this question is an excuse to post those images lol

Comment: The anime's story is original and Urame didn't appear in any game, so the game mechanic won't apply in here. (The enemy is different too; Nighteaters, not Bugged One). Though, the question is still valid...

Comment: Isn't it sunlight that destroys them? Having most of your skin exposed to sunlight killed the nighteaters in the games. This battle is happening at night, it seems.

Comment: @Sigfried666 In the anime they changed the explanation - it's exposure to _air_ that's harmful, not exposure to light.